# How to populate this nsdictionary data onto the uitableview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios7

How to populate this `NSDictionary` data onto the `UITableView`
I want

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Methods getting data out from that Dict

```
2015-07-11 13:19:50.972 demo[1226:23659] {
posts =     (
            {
        post =             {
            id = 1;
            "school_id" = 1;
            subject = Math;
        };
    },
            {
        post =             {
            id = 2;
            "school_id" = 1;
            subject = Science;
        };
    },
            {
        post =             {
            id = 3;
            "school_id" = 1;
            subject = English;
        };
    },
            {
        post =             {
            id = 5;
            "school_id" = 1;
            subject = Hindi;
        };
    },
            {
        post =             {
            id = 29;
            "school_id" = 1;
            subject = Biology;
        };
    }
);
}
```

Comment: You will not get any useful answer unless you start providing more explanation of what you want to achieve and show what you have tried so far - down vote and close flag.

Comment: see someone already answer my question and u know what it solved my problem. if you don't want to give an answer then why are u reading this .question was so easy if you can't solve this question then you are not welcome here.and you know what after this comment again someone will down vote this but i not going to harm me any way because i will create an another account on that i will get 4 points as start .try to solve question i am new in ios that way i can't be so specific to the point in my question

Comment: "i will create an another account on that i will get 4 points as start" i hate this kind of mindset sooooooo much (you realize that you are doing something wrong and just don't care). And you apparently have still (after many attempts) still not figured out how SO is supposed to work and how you are supposed to ask questions - poor guy. I beg you, read through the [How to ask section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before doing anything further.

Comment: what is wrong in that ..if someone can answer that question then why don't you .Dharmesh Dhorajiya has around 1200 reputation points and he understand my question and answered is so correctly .and you have more than 4000 reputation points and can't even understand my question .i feel sorry for you.

Comment: i accepting that i made a mistake in writing the question but you can explain me in comment .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way to get data from dictionary

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // if you use custom cell then use this way code
    FriendSelectionCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"friendSelectionCell"];
    // get value from dictionary
     cell.yourlabel.text=[[[[self.dict objectForKey:@"posts"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"post"] objectForKey:@"id"];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You could use slightly more modern syntax to access the dictionaries and arrays: `self.dict[@"posts"][indexPath.row][@"post"][@"id"]`